# How can I enable accumulation buffer with glutInitDisplayString?

Tags: opengl, initialization, glut

On Mac OS X, I'm able to enable the accumulation buffer in my glut app using

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE| GLUT_ACCUM);
```

then I see for example that `GL_ACCUM_RED_BITS` is set to 32.

But if I try to use the equivalent

```
glutInitDisplayString( "rgba depth double acca");
```

then the accumulation buffer is not enabled ( `GL_ACCUM_RED_BITS` is 0 ).

Are these two lines not equivalent? Is there no way to enable the accumulation buffer via `glutInitDisplayMode` ?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the number of bits? `"rgba 32 depth 24 double acca 128"`?

Comment: Even when accumulation buffers were somewhat common, 128-bit (32-bit per-component) would often throw you off the hardware path. If I recall the only way to get 128-bit on Windows is if you use the GDI rasterizer, tough I have not tried this in years. 64-bit (16-bit per-component) is far more likely to be supported.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, `acca 128` didn't help. Further, `GLUT_ACCUM` does seem to keep me in hardware mode.